# Create a flutter project without a web dependence

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

I want to create a new project in flutter using VS, but I want this project without the web dependence just a mobile app  dependence but each time I create a project it gives me the dependence of the web, not a mobile app
For Example, this what I get:

[image]

This what I want

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the same way you enabled flutter web support, disable it.

```dart
flutter config --no-enable-web
```

This removes web support so that future created projects will not generate a web folder. You may need to restart any open editors for the changes to take place.

Answer (score 11):

You can generate a flutter app for only mobile platforms with flutter create tool by specifying platforms.

```
flutter create <app_name> --platforms=android,ios
```